# Como fazer um site que se ajuste entre 970px e 1300px

Tags: css

Preciso fazer um site que fique com a resolução mínima de 970px, mas que se ajuste até no máximo 1300px de largura.

Pesquisando, eu encontrei algo assim:

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
}
```

Mas quanto ao mínimo? Como poderia ficar? Preciso usar Bootstrap para isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente acrescentando min-width.

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width:  970px;
}
```

Considere usar *[media-queries](http://blog.popupdesign.com.br/design-responsivo-iii-media-queries-e-compatibilidade/)* para atender outros formatos, se for o caso, como neste exemplo:

```
.div-principal {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width:  970px;
}

@media (max-width: 970px) {
   .div-principal {
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       max-width: 970px;
       min-width: 480px;
   }
   ... outras declaracoes adequadas para tamanho < 970 ...
}
```

> Se não quiser o "efeito" da página esticando, e sim centralizando apenas, ponha o max-width e o min-width na mesma medida.

Comment: Obrigado! Eu não gostaria de versão para celular, nem tablet. No caso seria exibido o site normal em 970px... Preciso mesmo assim usar as media-queries? E no caso poderia abandonar o bootstrap nesse projeto?

Comment: Provavelmente seria exagero usar bootstrap pra algo só em tela de desktop. Essas definições de css básico você pode simplesmente aplicar no <div> principal da página. Se é só pra desktop, esqueça o @media.

Comment: Cuidado ao usar o `@media`. No IE8 não irá funcionar.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo! O problema foi resolvido com o uso das Media Queries mesmo!

Comment: @Marcus disponha. Depois experimente as alternativas propostas na questão e dê uma lida geral no assunto, muita coisa você vai ver que o CSS simples resolve pra você numa boa.

Answer (score 1):

A dica dos media-queries já foi deixada e é o que mais se encaixa no seu problema provavelmente.
 Além do max-width e do min-width, você adicione um width com porcentagem para o seu container se adaptar a tela.
 Uma dica para testar como seu layout vai se adaptar em algumas telas é usar um iframe em uma página e alterar o width dele...
 Mas dependendo do seu objetivo, você talvez nem precise de media-queries.

```
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width:  970px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/LXvAE/2/embedded/result/

Mas se for usar, não é nada difícil adaptar seu layout a outras resoluções, basta dar uma pesquisada a respeito do assunto. 
Segue alguns links interessantes:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
- http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/