# Testar resolução igual site da Netshoes

Tags: javascript, css

Estava testando o site da Netshoes em várias resoluções, e vi que ele não passa de 1300px e tem um mínimo de 950px de largura. Quando você diminui a tela, ele não vai se ajustando (como utilizando o bootstrap, por exemplo), ele só se ajusta quando chega numa largura menor que x, e vice-versa.

Alguém sabe como isso está sendo feito? É com uso somente de CSS, ou tem JS?

Obrigado

Comment: Isso está sendo feito de forma responsiva. Aqui tem um bom tutorial de como fazer um site responsivo com CSS: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/responsive-website-tutorial/

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros É, eu sei que é responsivo... Mas eu gostaria de saber a forma que está sendo feito pra só alterar o css quando chegar em x resolução. Não pra ir se ajustando conforme vai mudando a resolução, pixel por pixel.

Comment: A resposta é a mesma que eu dei nesta questão que você fez anteriormente, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12050/como-fazer-um-site-que-se-ajuste-entre-970px-e-1300px . Se quiser mudar numa determinada medida, use o `@media`, como indicado. Você trava a resolução com min-max e usa o `@media` para travar em outros tamanhos. nao precisa nem de bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente eles usam media-queries para conseguir tal efeito.

Você pode ler mais a respeito aqui:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
- http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Segue um exemplo de como media queries podem ser usadas da maneira que você citou:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/euW2e/14/embedded/result/

Fiz rapidinho, só para testar mesmo, mas o conceito é esse..