# Como separar ícone do texto em uma <div>

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um elemento para meu site (que é responsivo), porém, eu não consigo deixar os elementos separados. Abaixo segue alguns prints:

#### Como está:

[image: Como está]

#### Como eu quero que fique:

[image: Como eu quero que fique.]

### [EXEMPLO - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/hnjuB/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode simplificar um pouco o código usando a imagem como fundo da div, e acrescentando um `padding` (espaçamento interno) maior do lado onde a imagem vai ficar.

No exemplo abaixo, note que foi acrescida a classe `passo1` ao `div`, eliminando a hierarquia redundante de elementos, assim como definido um padding de 100px na terceira linha do CSS, na margem esquerda. Adicionalmente, a imagem de fundo foi posicionada na definição da classe `.passo1`:

HTML:

```
<div class="flx-full-width tres-passos passo1">
   <h3>Escolha um dos Planos</h3>
   <p>
      Escolha um Plano que mais se adapta a você. 
      Quantidade de domínios, contas de e-mail,
      espaço ou banco de dados,
      de acordo com o que você precisa.
   </p>
   <p>
      Aumentei o texto para você ter uma noção do que acontece
      ao ter um texto mais longo. 
      Aumentei o texto para você ter uma noção do que acontece
      ao ter um texto mais longo. 
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flx-full-width {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 10px 25px 13px 100px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tres-passos {
   color:#69717A;
   border:1px solid #e9ecef;
   font: normal 16px Tahoma;
}
.tres-passos h3{
   font:normal 18px tahoma; margin:0; color:#00AFEF;
}
.passo1 {
   background: #f8f9fc url("http://testetabela.esy.es/1.png") no-repeat 12px 50%;
}
```

Exemplo no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49L5b/)**

Comment: Excelente @Bacco resolveu o problema! :D

Comment: Você poderia dar uma olhadinha nesse tópico?: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15480/como-deixar-um-elemento-responsivo

Comment: @AlexandreLopes pra falar a verdade, acho que ontem mesmo eu ja tinha apontado a solução, que é _media query_. Com media queries você indica partes do CSS separadas para resoluções diferentes, assim poderia ter um 100% de largura nas partes que estão encavalando, quando a resolução for menor que 800px, por exemplo. Infelizmente hoje não tenho como parar o que estou fazendo pra ajudar, mas dê uma espiada nesta questão, que é o melhor caminho: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12050/como-fazer-um-site-que-se-ajuste-entre-970px-e-1300px

Comment: Em resumo, depois do seu css atual, você acrescenta isso: `@media (max-width: 800px) { ` e põe alterações no CSS que vai valer pro celular. Por exemplo, tirar o float de um elemento, colocar 100% e clear=both no campo que está quebrando, etc. Basta repetir os elementos que vai mexer, com as propriedades novas. Não precisa por o CSS inteiro aí, só o que mudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, agora vou passar um ano para poder fazer funcionar...rsrs

Answer (score 2):

Eu criei uma solução com algumas modificações no seu exemplo, verifique se resolve o seu problema, e se lhe atente, verifique o [exemplo atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/hnjuB/5/).

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, sim, percebi aqui, é que minha resolução está um pouco maior que a sua, e achei que tinha funcionado, vou verificar aqui.

Comment: Não tem problema, o que vale é a intenção :D
Só de querer tentar me ajudar, já fico feliz. :P

Comment: Opa, agora sim, você acertou em cheio!

Comment: Não consegui ajustar seu exemplo, eu quero o ícone fique bem no meio na vertical, só que ele não fica. http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/hnjuB/7/