# Como deixar um elemento responsivo

Tags: css

Estou tendo problemas com um elemento em meu site, ele fica normal no computador, mais em resoluções menores (celulares), ele não fica responsivo.

Abaixo segue alguns prints:

### Como está no Computador: *(Certo)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Como está no Celular: *(ERRADO!)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### *Como TEM que ficar no Celular: (Certíssimo!)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que fique como no 3° Print.

Segue o código:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buscar_dominio">
<div class="tamanho">
    <div class="esquerdo">      
        <div class="buscar_secao">        
        <form method="post" id="dominio-form-busca">
        <input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
        <div class="www"><label for="s" class="www-texto">www.</label></div>       
        <div>
        <input class="input" name="domain" id="s" value="Insira seu domínio aqui" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Insira seu domínio aqui') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Insira seu domínio aqui';}" type="text" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <select class="witch" name="ext">
            <option value=".com">.com</option>
            <option value=".net">.net</option>
            <option value=".org">.org</option>
            <option value=".com.br">.com.br</option>
            <option value=".net.br">.net.br</option>
            <option value=".in">.in</option>
            <option value=".me">.me</option>
            <option value=".info">.info</option>
            <option value=".biz">.biz</option>
            <option value=".us">.us</option>
            <option value=".name">.name</option>
            <option value=".cc">.cc</option>
            <option value=".ws">.ws</option>
            <option value=".mobi">.mobi</option>
            <option value=".tv">.tv</option>
            <option value=".co">.co</option>
            <option value=".br.com">.br.com</option>
            <option value=".xxx">.xxx</option>
        </select>
        <input id="botao-busca" value="Buscar" type="submit"> 
        </div>
        </form>        
        </div>        
        <div class="clearfix"></div>        
        <div class="sm_links"><a href="#">Tabela de Preços</a>  | <a href="#">Pesquisa de Domínios em Massa</a> | <a href="#">Transferir Domínio</a> | <a href="#">Promoções</a></div>        
    </div>
    <div class="bg-transparente"><ul><li> Aqui irá ficar o título</li><li class="titulo">Aqui ficará o sub-título</li><li class="porque">Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris.</li></ul></div>    
    <div class="direito">       
        <ul>
            <li>.COM<em>Apenas</em> R$ 22,90/ano</li>
            <li class="promo">.ORG<em>De <s>R$ 27,90</s> por</em> R$ 13,90/ano</li>
            <li>.NET<em>Apenas</em> R$ 19,90/ano</li>
            <li>.COM.BR<em>Apenas</em> R$ 34,90/ano</li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{font:normal 14px arial;}

a {text-decoration:none; }

.buscar_dominio {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background:#EEE; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo {
    float: left;
    width: 54%;
    padding: 16px 0px 5px 0px; }

.buscar_dominio .direito {
    width: 57%;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 20px 0px 16px 0px; }

.buscar_dominio .bg-transparente {
    float: right;
    width: 43%;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    font:normal 28px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    color: #000; }

.buscar_dominio .porque {
    font:normal 13pt Arial;
    width:90%;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 7%;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center; }

.buscar_dominio .titulo {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;}

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .buscar_secao {
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 1.4% 1.6%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; }

#dominio-form-busca { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#dominio-form-busca #s{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
    width: 45%;
    height:30px;
    padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
    color: #393a3b;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3; }

.www {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 8%;
    height:30px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
    color: #393a3b;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    font: normal 14px arial;
    background-color: #FFEB00; }

.www-texto {
    margin-top:4px;
    cursor:default;
    font-size:14pt; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .buscar_secao .witch {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #393a3b;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px -10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    background-color: #FFEB00; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .buscar_secao #botao-busca{
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 16px tahoma;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #004897;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .sm_links {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 5px; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .sm_links a {
     color: #999; }

.buscar_dominio .esquerdo .sm_links a:hover {
     color: #0099FF; }

.buscar_dominio .direito ul {
     padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

.buscar_dominio .direito li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 8px 13px 8px;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #393a3b;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #DBDBDB; }

.buscar_dominio .direito li em {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #727272;
    font-style: normal;
    display: block;
    line-height: 16px; }

.buscar_dominio .direito s { color: #C30; }

.buscar_dominio .direito .promo { color: #00AC00; }

ul li {list-style: none;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/XS4w6/)

Comment: Sinceramente, seu exemplo é muito ruim (o css está uma bagunça) além de ser amplo demais. Reduza sua questão pra algo mais pontual (dificilmente alguém vai transformar seu exemplo em uma versão responsiva). Recomendo pesquisar sobre [@media](http://blog.popupdesign.com.br/design-responsivo-iii-media-queries-e-compatibilidade/) e outras técnicas de design responsivo, como medidas relativas.

Comment: @Beterraba
porque está uma bagunça? acho que você está vendo coisas...

Comment: Não está legível. Não tem quebra de linhas, não tem endentação...

Comment: O que o @Beterraba pede é simples "me ajuda a te ajudar". Pedir ajuda de programadores mostrando código sem indentar é como ir ao dentista depois de almoçar sem escovar os dentes.

Comment: Vou arrumar então.

Comment: Pronto, podem entrar no mesmo link que já quebrei as linhas.
Alguém ajuda?

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema, resolvi com ajuda de [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 2):

Porque não utiliza bootstrap em seu projeto? Com a estrutura do mesmo, você pode definir o tamanho e posição das colunas para seu projeto de modo a qual com o redimensionamento de tela/troca de resolução, seu conteúdo se adapte.

Comment: Olá @Rafael Barbosa como eu não encontrei solução aqui, eu fui lá no freelancer.com e contratei um cara da romania por 30 dólares. E ficou perfeito.